# Stack Overflow UI related issue

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, design

Today when i opened Stack overflow i saw this :

[image]

So i thought some problem with net , 
I asked the person sitting near me to open SO but he was having same issue.

I want to know is it because anything wrong in our network or anything else?

While searching i found below errors.

[image]

It might be because our System Admins might have removed some permission to access something?

Because `403` is there.

Comment: Check if the stuff mentioned in [What else do I need](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/158100) works for you.

Comment: Something on your side is blocking a domain that is used for the CSS resources of Stack Overflow. For example company firewall and/or proxy.

Comment: I have checked it in my Mobile which is not connected with my office network but still it is not loaded correctly..it might be a nation wide issue? @ShadowWizard

Comment: If you're in China then yes, this might be nation wide. Otherwise, might be local ISP issue.